# Does Django get() performs query to database on values()?

Tags: python, django, database, optimization, django-queryset

I have values queryset, if I get some date from it, does this perform a call to the database?

```
instances_values = Model.objects.filter(**kwargs).values(*args)
instance_with_id_one = instances_values.get(id=1) # does this perform a call to the databse?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, a `.get(..)` is *eager*. It performs a query. Your `instance_with_id_one` is here a dictionary that will contain the values listed in your `values(..)` call.

You can use a `.filter(..)` to postpone the call. Then it will only make a call when you *consume* the queryset (for example by iterating over it). But then it is thus a collection of (in this case at most one) record.